For a symmetric FIR filter, can the number of coefficients be even and half of the filter order?
I'm trying to use an assembly DSP library (TriLib by Infineon) and for one of the FIR functions, FirSym_4_16, the implementation has the following constrains:

Number of coefficients given by user should be even and half of the filter order
Optimal implementation requires filter order to be multiple of four

My understanding is that for symmetrical FIR filters even order have odd number of coefficients (Ex. order=12, coefficients=7) and odd order have even number of coefficients (Ex. order=11, coefficients=6)
One example given on the library source code has this:
#define     nH2_2   6                   //Filter Order/2

//Filter Coefficients in 1Q15 with DataS defined as short
DataS   H2[nH2_2] =
{0x4000, 0x4ccc, 0x028f, 0x170a, 0x2b85, 0x3333}; 

//Delay-Buffer 
DataS  DLY2[nH2_2*2];   

The wording of the constrains confuses me and i don t think its possible to meet. If their documentation said "Filter length" instead of order would make sense to me, but as it is it doesn't.
Is there anything im missing on the library docs or misunderstanding of symmetric FIR filters?
The user manual for the library is found here: TriLib User Manual. The description of the function is at page 142 of the pdf.

For an FIR, the filter order is one less than the number of taps.  To be symmetric and having the number of taps being a multiple of 4, then the number of unique tap values is half of that, a multiple of 2, which is an even number.

@robertbristow-johnson Agree with that, but no where in the lib user manual they say anything about the non-unique center tab coefficient, neither on the example or source code implementation

For an even number of taps (filter order is odd) then the delay is exactly half of the filter order.  That's where the line of symmetry is.  If it's an odd number of taps and an even filter order, that line of symmetry (which is also the delay of the symmetric FIR filter) is an integer number of taps.  But with the even number of taps, it's 1/2 tap more delay.

So there are two identical taps in the middle.  Then two more identical taps surrounding the first pair in the middle.  Then another identical pair outside of that.

This function specifies symmetric filters, so only supplying half the coefficients makes sense to me – the other half is the same coefficients, "mirrored".
This implies that these filters are even-length (so, odd-order, because order=length-1).
An extra constraint is that the half-length needs to be even, so the full filter length is divisible by 4. That's what the _4_ in the function name is for!


Number of coefficients given by user should be even and half of the filter order


Yeah, the filter order is odd, so they made a mistake here, and meant to write "length". But the context, I'd say, is clear: they want you to define half the filter.


Optimal implementation requires filter order to be multiple of four


You added a numbering to these two sentences as if they were equal constraints, but they're not: this is just a reminder of why you're using FirSym_4_16 instead of just FirSym_16; it's an explanation for why the filter length is a multiple of four.

Yeah, after reading carefully the implementation details they state this on a couple different functions ...equal to the filter order, i.e., twice the number of given coefficients.... so it seems in this document they talk about the filter order as the same as the filter length which caused my confusion. Thanks for your help clarifying this.

no need to thank me, it's not your fault the documentation abuses terminology. (it's bit surprising, because this is pretty stereotypical Siemens documentation, a lot of things feel very "German" about it to me, and usually, us Germans are the sticklers for order!=length.)
